# Reference dynamic object key via computed property name

Tags: typescript

I got the following types defined as

```
/**
* Examples of Bazzs:
*
* {
*     "BigBazz": {
*       "beb": "bebbing",
*       "bab": "babbing",
*       "bob": {
*         "clearlyBobbing": "bobobobobobobobob"
*       }
*     }
*     "BiggerBazz": {
*       "beb": "bebbing",
*       "bab": "babbing",
*       "bob": {
*         "notSoBobbing": "bo...b"
*       }
*     }
* }
*/

enum BobNoise = {
  CLEARLY_BOBBING = "clearlyBobbing",
  NOT_SO_BOBBING = "notSoBobbing"
}

type Bobs = {
  [bob in BobNoise]?: string
}

export type Bazz = {
  [bazName: string]: {
    beb: string
    bab: string
    bob: Bobs
  }
}
```

I want to dynamically access the correct bob value using computed property names as such

```
...some myBaz compute...

const isBobbing = "notSoBobbing"

// here I expect TS to know the bobbingBazString I want is "bo...b"
const bobbingBazString = myBaz.bob[isBobbing]
```

however my linter gives the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BobNoise'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'BobNoise'
```

Now I suspect this is because ts compiler isn't aware at compile-time of the Bazzs objects which are only inferred / computed at runtime, but I'm not really sure I fully understand the problem.

Why's it erroring like that and is there any magic I can do to make the compiler understand what I want to do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've changed the example, that's not the issue I'm having. Assume myBaz has the correct type. My bad for that.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without typos (e.g., `enum X = {` is invalid syntax) and with the definitions needed for others to reproduce (e.g., replace pseudocode like "`...some myBaz compute...`" with actual code that demonstrates the issue).  The idea is that others can paste the code into their IDEs and immediately get to work on the problem. That will make it more likely you get an answer that helps your.

Comment: I think it is the enum declaration. Remove the equal sign so it reads `enum BobNoise{...}` (no equal sign)